# Video compression using Telegram API rotating the video issue

Tags: android, video, compression

I am trying to compress the video.
The code works fine if the video is in landscape mode, but gets rotated to landscape if the video is in portrait mode.
My code:

```
public File convertVideo(String path) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);

        retriever.setDataSource(path);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String width = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    String height = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
    String rotation = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);

    long startTime = -1;
    long endTime = -1;

    int resultWidth = 640;
    int resultHeight = 360;

    int maxPortWidth = 360;
    int maxPortHeight = 640;

    int maxLandWidth = 640;
    int maxLandHeight = 360;

    float imgRatio;
    float maxRatio;


    int rotationValue = Integer.valueOf(rotation);
    int originalWidth = Integer.valueOf(width);
    int originalHeight = Integer.valueOf(height);


    int bitrate = 921600;
    int rotateRender = 0;

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  File.separator
            + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME);
    boolean isDirExist = false;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        isDirExist = folder.mkdir();
    }
    isDirExist = false;
    folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  File.separator
            + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME+ Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_COMPRESSED_VIDEOS_DIR);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        isDirExist = folder.mkdir();
    }

    File cacheFile = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator
                    + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
                    + Config.VIDEO_COMPRESSOR_COMPRESSED_VIDEOS_DIR,
            "VIDEO_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + ".mp4"
    );

    if(rotation.equals("90") || rotation.equals("270")) {

        imgRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
        maxRatio = maxPortWidth / maxPortHeight;
        if (originalHeight > maxPortHeight || originalWidth > maxPortWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxPortHeight / originalHeight;
                resultWidth = (int) (imgRatio * originalWidth);
                resultHeight = (int) maxPortHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxPortWidth / originalWidth;
                resultHeight = (int) (imgRatio * originalHeight);
                resultWidth = (int) maxPortWidth;
            } else {
                resultHeight = (int) maxPortHeight;
                resultWidth = (int) maxPortWidth;

            }
        }           

    } else {

        imgRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
        maxRatio = maxLandWidth / maxLandHeight;
        if (originalHeight > maxLandHeight || originalWidth > maxLandWidth) {
            if (imgRatio!=0.0 && (imgRatio < maxRatio)) {
                imgRatio = maxLandHeight / originalHeight;
                resultWidth = (int) (imgRatio * originalWidth);
                resultHeight = (int) maxLandHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio!=0.0 && (imgRatio > maxRatio)) {
                imgRatio = maxLandWidth / originalWidth;
                resultHeight = (int) (imgRatio * originalHeight);
                resultWidth = (int) maxLandWidth;
            } else {
                resultHeight = (int) maxLandHeight;
                resultWidth = (int) maxLandWidth;

            }
        }
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18 && resultHeight > resultWidth && resultWidth != originalWidth && resultHeight != originalHeight) {
        int temp = resultHeight;
        resultHeight = resultWidth;
        resultWidth = temp;
        rotationValue = 90;
        rotateRender = 270;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
        if(rotationValue == 0) {

            rotateRender = 0;
        } else if (rotationValue == 90) {
            int temp = resultHeight;
            resultHeight = resultWidth;
            resultWidth = temp;
            rotationValue = 0;
            rotateRender = 270;
        } else if (rotationValue == 180) {
            rotateRender = 180;
            rotationValue = 0;
        } else if (rotationValue == 270) {
            int temp = resultHeight;
            resultHeight = resultWidth;
            resultWidth = temp;
            rotationValue = 0;
            rotateRender = 90;
        }
    }
    File inputFile = new File(path);
    if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
        didWriteData(true, true);
        return null;
    } else {
    }

    videoConvertFirstWrite = true;
    boolean error = false;
    long videoStartTime = startTime;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (resultWidth != 0 && resultHeight != 0) {
        MP4Builder mediaMuxer = null;
        MediaExtractor extractor = null;

        try {
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            Mp4Movie movie = new Mp4Movie();
            movie.setCacheFile(cacheFile);
            movie.setRotation(rotationValue);
            movie.setSize(resultWidth, resultHeight);
            mediaMuxer = new MP4Builder().createMovie(movie);
            extractor = new MediaExtractor();
            extractor.setDataSource(inputFile.toString());


            if (resultWidth != originalWidth || resultHeight != originalHeight) {
                int videoIndex;
                videoIndex = selectTrack(extractor, false);

                if (videoIndex >= 0) {
                    MediaCodec decoder = null;
                    MediaCodec encoder = null;
                    InputSurface inputSurface = null;
                    OutputSurface outputSurface = null;
                    try {
                        long videoTime = -1;
                        boolean outputDone = false;
                        boolean inputDone = false;
                        boolean decoderDone = false;
                        int swapUV = 0;
                        int videoTrackIndex = -5;

                        int colorFormat;
                        int processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_OTHER;
                        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER.toLowerCase();
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
                            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
                            if (colorFormat == 0) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("no supported color format");
                            }
                            String codecName = codecInfo.getName();
                            if (codecName.contains("OMX.qcom.")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_QCOM;
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 16) {
                                    if (manufacturer.equals("lge") || manufacturer.equals("nokia")) {
                                        swapUV = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (codecName.contains("OMX.Intel.")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_INTEL;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_MTK;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_SEC;
                                swapUV = 1;
                            } else if (codecName.equals("OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E")) {
                                processorType = PROCESSOR_TYPE_TI;
                            }
                            Log.e("tmessages", "codec = " + codecInfo.getName() + " manufacturer = " + manufacturer + "device = " + Build.MODEL);
                        } else {
                            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface;
                        }


                        int resultHeightAligned = resultHeight;
                        int padding = 0;
                        int bufferSize = resultWidth * resultHeight * 3 / 2;
                        if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_OTHER) {
                            if (resultHeight % 16 != 0) {
                                resultHeightAligned += (16 - (resultHeight % 16));
                                padding = resultWidth * (resultHeightAligned - resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding * 5 / 4;
                            }
                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_QCOM) {
                            if (!manufacturer.toLowerCase().equals("lge")) {
                                int uvoffset = (resultWidth * resultHeight + 2047) & ~2047;
                                padding = uvoffset - (resultWidth * resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding;
                            }
                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_TI) {

                        } else if (processorType == PROCESSOR_TYPE_MTK) {
                            if (manufacturer.equals("baidu")) {
                                resultHeightAligned += (16 - (resultHeight % 16));
                                padding = resultWidth * (resultHeightAligned - resultHeight);
                                bufferSize += padding * 5 / 4;
                            }
                        }

                        extractor.selectTrack(videoIndex);
                        if (startTime > 0) {
                            extractor.seekTo(startTime, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
                        } else {
                            extractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);
                        }
                        MediaFormat inputFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(videoIndex);

                        MediaFormat outputFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, resultWidth, resultHeight);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate != 0 ? bitrate : 921600);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
                        outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 10);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                            outputFormat.setInteger("stride", resultWidth + 32);
                            outputFormat.setInteger("slice-height", resultHeight);
                        }

                        encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
                        encoder.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                            inputSurface = new InputSurface(encoder.createInputSurface());
                            inputSurface.makeCurrent();
                        }
                        encoder.start();

                        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(inputFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                            outputSurface = new OutputSurface();
                        } else {
                            outputSurface = new OutputSurface(resultWidth, resultHeight, rotateRender);
                        }
                        decoder.configure(inputFormat, outputSurface.getSurface(), null, 0);
                        decoder.start();

                        final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 2500;
                        ByteBuffer[] decoderInputBuffers = null;
                        ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = null;
                        ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers = null;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                            decoderInputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                            encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
                                encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();
                            }
                        }

                        while (!outputDone) {
                            if (!inputDone) {
                                boolean eof = false;
                                int index = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
                                if (index == videoIndex) {
                                    int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                        ByteBuffer inputBuf;
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                            inputBuf = decoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                                        } else {
                                            inputBuf = decoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                                        }
                                        int chunkSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuf, 0);
                                        if (chunkSize < 0) {
                                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                            inputDone = true;
                                        } else {
                                            decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, chunkSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                                            extractor.advance();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if (index == -1) {
                                    eof = true;
                                }
                                if (eof) {
                                    int inputBufIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                        inputDone = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            boolean decoderOutputAvailable = !decoderDone;
                            boolean encoderOutputAvailable = true;
                            while (decoderOutputAvailable || encoderOutputAvailable) {
                                int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                    encoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                        encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
                                    }
                                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                    MediaFormat newFormat = encoder.getOutputFormat();
                                    if (videoTrackIndex == -5) {
                                        videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat, false);
                                    }
                                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException("unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
                                } else {
                                    ByteBuffer encodedData;
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                                        encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
                                    } else {
                                        encodedData = encoder.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                                    }
                                    if (encodedData == null) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                                    }
                                    if (info.size > 1) {
                                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) == 0) {
                                            if (mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, encodedData, info, false)) {
                                                didWriteData(false, false);
                                            }
                                        } else if (videoTrackIndex == -5) {
                                            byte[] csd = new byte[info.size];
                                            encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);
                                            encodedData.position(info.offset);
                                            encodedData.get(csd);
                                            ByteBuffer sps = null;
                                            ByteBuffer pps = null;
                                            for (int a = info.size - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                                                if (a > 3) {
                                                    if (csd[a] == 1 && csd[a - 1] == 0 && csd[a - 2] == 0 && csd[a - 3] == 0) {
                                                        sps = ByteBuffer.allocate(a - 3);
                                                        pps = ByteBuffer.allocate(info.size - (a - 3));
                                                        sps.put(csd, 0, a - 3).position(0);
                                                        pps.put(csd, a - 3, info.size - (a - 3)).position(0);
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            MediaFormat newFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, resultWidth, resultHeight);
                                            if (sps != null && pps != null) {
                                                newFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", sps);
                                                newFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", pps);
                                            }
                                            videoTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat, false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    outputDone = (info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0;
                                    encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                                }
                                if (encoderStatus != MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                                if (!decoderDone) {
                                    int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                    if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                                        decoderOutputAvailable = false;
                                    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {

                                    } else if (decoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                                        MediaFormat newFormat = decoder.getOutputFormat();

                                    } else if (decoderStatus < 0) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("unexpected result from decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + decoderStatus);
                                    } else {
                                        boolean doRender;
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0;
                                        } else {
                                            doRender = info.size != 0 || info.presentationTimeUs != 0;
                                        }
                                        if (endTime > 0 && info.presentationTimeUs >= endTime) {
                                            inputDone = true;
                                            decoderDone = true;
                                            doRender = false;
                                            info.flags |= MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM;
                                        }
                                        if (startTime > 0 && videoTime == -1) {
                                            if (info.presentationTimeUs < startTime) {
                                                doRender = false;

                                            } else {
                                                videoTime = info.presentationTimeUs;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, doRender);
                                        if (doRender) {
                                            boolean errorWait = false;
                                            try {
                                                outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                errorWait = true;

                                            }
                                            if (!errorWait) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                    outputSurface.drawImage(false);
                                                    inputSurface.setPresentationTime(info.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
                                                    inputSurface.swapBuffers();
                                                } else {
                                                    int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                        outputSurface.drawImage(true);
                                                        ByteBuffer rgbBuf = outputSurface.getFrame();
                                                        ByteBuffer yuvBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];
                                                        yuvBuf.clear();
                                                        convertVideoFrame(rgbBuf, yuvBuf, colorFormat, resultWidth, resultHeight, padding, swapUV);
                                                        encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, bufferSize, info.presentationTimeUs, 0);
                                                    } else {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                                            decoderOutputAvailable = false;

                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                                                encoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
                                            } else {
                                                int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
                                                if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                                                    encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 1, info.presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (videoTime != -1) {
                            videoStartTime = videoTime;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        error = true;
                    }

                    extractor.unselectTrack(videoIndex);

                    if (outputSurface != null) {
                        outputSurface.release();
                    }
                    if (inputSurface != null) {
                        inputSurface.release();
                    }
                    if (decoder != null) {
                        decoder.stop();
                        decoder.release();
                    }
                    if (encoder != null) {
                        encoder.stop();
                        encoder.release();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                long videoTime = readAndWriteTrack(extractor, mediaMuxer, info, startTime, endTime, cacheFile, false);

                if (videoTime != -1) {
                    videoStartTime = videoTime;
                }
            }
            if (!error) {
                readAndWriteTrack(extractor, mediaMuxer, info, videoStartTime, endTime, cacheFile, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = true;

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (extractor != null) {
                extractor.release();
            }
            if (mediaMuxer != null) {
                try {
                    mediaMuxer.finishMovie(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {


                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        didWriteData(true, true);
        return null;
    }
    didWriteData(true, error);

    return cacheFile;
}
```

Telegram App video compression
https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lalongooo/videocompressor/video/MediaController.java

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Simply put the condition before calling the compression function. Check the selected video height and width using MediaMetaDataRetriever and set if condition.For 1:1 ratio video also it converts to 640x360. So try to get Width and Height before compression and put logic for compress or not.

```
public void compress() {

Log.w("VideoMessage","eNTERED : "+inputPath);
lMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(inputPath);
String lVideoWidth = lMediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
Log.w("VideoMessage","VideoWidth: "+lVideoWidth);
String lVideoHeight = lMediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
Log.w("VideoMessage","VideoHeight: "+lVideoHeight);
if(Integer.valueOf(lVideoWidth)<=640 || Integer.valueOf(lVideoHeight)<=360){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video Already in compressed form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    try2CreateCompressDir();
    outPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + APP_DIR
            + COMPRESSED_VIDEOS_DIR
            +"VIDEO_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + ".mp4";

    new VideoCompressor.execute(inputPath,outPath);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in that MediaController code which is rotating the video when source video and converted video resolutions are same. In order to get the correct video conversion, you have to specify a width/height for conversion which doesn't match the source video width/height.